# unable to enter BIOS after dual booting with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: uefi, windows-8, lenovo, intel, bios

I have Lenovo (G580 Model 20157) laptop. It had Windows 8.1. I dual booted it with Ubuntu 15.04. I am unable to go into BIOS setup since then. I tried that by:

Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>,<kbd>F4</kbd>,<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys.

By using Novo button.
From windows 8.1 Update and recovery options.
By turning of fast start up option and hibernate option in power options.
Using Shift key while shutting down for complete shut down.
But it didn't work. When I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> key it says:

```
System bios shadowed Video BIOS shadowed
```

I tried to find the BIOS update for Windows 8.1 but I didn't find it. Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 2):

When running Windows, hold down the shift key and select "restart" instead of "shutdown".  At the restart, you will get an options screen, select "trouble shooting", then on the next screen, select the "UEFI settings" (the BIOS).

Comment: Some boot loaders and boot managers offer an option to reboot into the setup utility, too. GRUB supports this feature, but it's not always present on the boot menu. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) supports this feature, too, as does gummiboot (which is now folded into systemd as, IIRC, systemd-boot).

Comment: I tried. But that didn't solve my problem.